# Deleting Chrome Extensions Using Google Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-chrome-extension

I recently wanted to delete a couple of extensions off of my computer, however, There is an extension that is not from the chrome web store and the button to remove it wasn't there. So, I want to chrome://system and I found the extension id. However, I need to remove the extension through google scripts. I tried searching some things up online, and I found the code:

```
function deleteExtension(extensionId) {
  var chromeManagement = ChromeManagement.new();
  chromeManagement.chromeManagement.extensions.remove(extensionId);
}
```

I replaced the `extensionId` in the function with the actual quoted id and ran it, but an error occured:

```
ReferenceError: ChromeManagement is not defined
deleteExtension @ Code.gs:2
```

I tried searching it up online, but nothing seemed to help, and I didn't find any answers. Could someone please give me insight on why my code isn't working, or other ways to remove the extension only with the id?

(Please keep in mind that I barely know what I am doing because I have never really used google scripts before).

Comment: Not possible. Apps script runs on Google's server. Chrome extensions runs on your browser, client side. `button to remove it wasn't there`:  This topic maybe better addressed at [webapps.se]

Comment: Okay, thanks for letting me know!

Comment: On second thought I think I'm wrong. While the extension runs on the browser, the extension installed/authorized information is in Google servers.  I believe you should be able to access  "ChromeManagement API", by following instructions [here using urlfetch](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#advanced_services_or_http)

Comment: Checking chrome management api(https://developers.google.com/chrome/management/guides/app_details_api), there seems to be no method to delete a extension. Even if you are able to connect apps script to chrome extensions, you can't delete a extension, at least not through this api. Where exactly did you find the code? Seems to be nonsense spouted by chatgpt..

Comment: I forgot where I found it but I was looking through multiple sites and I conjured up this. I never really used google scripts before.

Comment: @TheMaster The Chrome Management API might work for managed computers.  If the user is working on his computer, it is very unlikely that he would like to handle all the hassle required to make a single computer a managed computer. That might be convenient for an IT admin / support, I think.

Comment: @Rubén Ahh.. I see.  Even if he did go through all the hassle,  there's no api method to delete a extension even in chrome management API.

Comment: @TheMaster I do not remember all the details, but I think it's possible to handle several Chrome / device settings for Workspace admins, I am not sure if this is a combination of Chrome Management API plus Workspace Admin SDK, or configuration files to run on each machine. I never did this alone; I just read and discussed with coworkers and friends about this. Maybe I'm confused with Chrome apps. Anyway, this is not something to be developed in detail on this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: Forget about using Google Apps Script for deleting Chrome extensions from the local instance of Google Chrome (unmanaged).

Note: If you were an admin managing remote machines, you might have a chance to do that.

If this is something to be done on a single machine, the best is to do it manually or with the help of remote desktop software. Another option is to run a command line script in your computer console / terminal.

---

Google Apps Script might be easily misunderstood as many things that Google does. I will not delve deep into all the details, just the essentials.

On https://script.google.com you find your Google Apps Script projects having a Google Cloud default or standard project linked to them.

A Google Apps Script project might have server-side and client-side code. The client-side code is executed on Google servers, while the client-side code is executed on the user's web browser, which calls a web app, dialog or sidebar.

Google Apps Script's server-side code can't do anything on the user's web browser. General client-side code might do a limited variety of tasks with certain conditions but the client-side code served by Google Apps Script doesn't meet all the conditions that might be required.

This happens because Google Apps Script serves the client-side code embedded inside several layers of nested iframes and the project owner and editors aren't able to change how most of those iframes work.